# Razor Syntax / WebMatrix - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, razor, webmatrix

I'm just starting out with WebMatrix and would like to know how to style a `@Html.TextBox("email")` and `@Html.Password("password")` control?

I've tried (in my CSS file):

```
.email{
   /* styles here */
}

.password{
   /* styles here */
}
```

But that has no effect at all. How can we style these types of controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indicate what class to use when creating the text box with an anonymous type like so: `@Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { @class="email" })`

Comment: I should've mentioned, the anonymous type can contain any attributes you want added to the element when it's created. Not Just class. For example: @Html.TextBox("Email", new { width="150px", height="50px" })

Comment: *@Html.TextBox("email", new { @class="email"})* isn't working. Instead of applying the styles, the value of the textbox becomes: { class=email }

Comment: Sorry about that, was thinking of the strongly typed helper. Instead try @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { @class="email" }). The second parameter there is what populates the textboxs value.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the confusion!